# How to obtain the width and height of an image using arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583265/how-can-i-determine-type-and-size-of-common-image-types-in-python) shows how to obtain the pixel dimensions of an image using Python.

Is it possible to find an image's height and width using arcpy and ArcGIS?

[arcpy.Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Describe/03q30000008q000000/) would seem like a logical place to start, but I can't see whether it returns the height and width properties. I looked at [File Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/File_properties/03q300000058000000/) and [Raster Dataset Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Raster_Dataset_properties/03q300000017000000/) - am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import arcpy

someRaster = arcpy.sa.Raster('TYPE HERE LINK TO YOUR RASTER')
someExtent = someRaster.extent

print someExtent
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks, great tip. I notice arcpy seems take the centre of each pixel (an 849 x 955 image is reported as -0.5, -954.4, 848.5, 0.5)

Comment: This seems even better (just found it): http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m7000000